# Image capture/upload with Phonegap (cordova) for iPhone not working

Tags: iphone, cordova, upload, camera

I have been trying to set up an app through PhoneGap (Cordova) to take images and upload them to our server. I have gone through so many of the responses on here and tried the code in them. I can get the camera up and taking a photo, I can access the phone gallery even. But I can not get it to send the image to the server. I've tried sending the image, and even sending the base64 image stream. I can't get it to the server.

Here is the javascript on the client side:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

}

function ImageUpload() {
    this.useExistingPhoto = function(e) {
        this.capture(Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);
    }

    this.takePhoto = function(e) {
        this.capture(Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
    }

    this.capture = function(sourceType) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onCaptureSuccess, this.onCaptureFaile, {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            soureType: sourceType,
            correctOrientation: true
        });
    }

    this.onCaptureSuccess = function(imageURI) {
        var fail, ft, options, params, win;

        success = function(response) {
            alert("Your photo has been uploaded!");
        };

        fail = function(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code + "\nMessage = "+error.message);
        };

        options = new FailUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = "text/plain";
        params = {
            val1: "some value",
            val2: "some other value"
        };
        options.params = params;
        ft= new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, 'http://style.appdev01.com/app/client-profile.php', success, faile, options);
    }

    this.OnCaptureFail = function(message) {
        alert("Failed because: "+message);
    }
};
var imageuploader = new ImageUpload();
```

Two buttons call imageuploader.takePhoto and .useExistingPhoto on click.

On the server side I have this php:
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {

```
$target_path = "/home/style/public_html/images/client_images/app_image.jpg";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

$insert = "INSERT INTO
    `fut`
SET
    `request` = '".serialize($_POST)."',
    `file` = '".serialize($_FILES)."'";
$mysql->query($insert);
```

}

This is just to store the POST and FILE arrays to the db to make sure they came through and create the image.

But again, nothing is getting to the server. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I've tried so many versions of this code from so many questions here and all over the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))); /* echo SITE_ROOT; to dir
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],SITE_ROOT."/uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]); // will move file, make sure uplaods has write permission!
```

That works for me on Android Simulator, not on Tablet, but let me know if you have it working, busy on the same thing.

```
$myarray = array( $_REQUEST);
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {

    echo "<p>".$key."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

That you can use to check POST / GET!

Answer (score 0):

Try this is my code. It has worked for me.

1. Encode your URL by encodeURI method
2. fileKey with "file" as in your server side script $_FILES['file']

   ```
   uploadFile: function(refNo){
   var uri = fileUpload.fileUri;
   var file = uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

   var options = new FileUploadOptions();
   options.fileKey = "file"; 
   options.fileName = file;
   options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
   alert("name === "+uri);
   options.chunkedMode = false;


   var ft = new FileTransfer();
   Common.ajaxLoading('show');


   ft.upload(uri,encodeURI("http://172.16.1.147:80/upload/home.php") , fileUpload.uploadSuccess, fileUpload.uploadFail, options, true);
   },
   ```